# Arcpy turns off all fields in a MXD file that all of the values are Null

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to turn off all fields in a MXD that have all null values.

I have been looking at a `SearchCursor` without much luck.

Comment: I don't understand what "turn off" a field means or why you would think you should use a SearchCursor to "turn off" a field.  I think you really mean that you want to filter out all features/records that have all null values.  You can do that with a definition query on a layer or a query that applies to a SearchCursor.  That would be done usng SQL like: NOT (FIELD1 IS NULL AND FIELD2 IS NULL)

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would take is create a list of all fields in the featureclass. Start a SearchCursor, and check all fields for a non-null value. If a non-null value is found, remove that field from the list.

```
    nullFields = [y.name for y in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc):
        for x in nullFields[:]: #must use a copy of nullFields here
            if not row.isNull(x):
                nullFields.remove(x)
```

The remaining items in `nullfields` will have all null values.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to remove from the list. I want to turn off a field that has all null values in all the layers in a MXD.

Comment: The code above determines all of the fields in a feature class that contains all null values. You can add whatever code you need to 'turn off' the fields in the resulting list, and wrap it all in a loop that will examine all of the layers in the MXD.

Comment: If you want to make a field invisible you need to use the FieldInfo properties interface and use the SetVisible method to change the visibility of a field index to False. You can find the field index from the Field Name using the findFieldByName method. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000074000000

Comment: - 1 because a) OP doesn't want to remove fields and b) you don't iterate through all records to check if they are all Null

Comment: @FelixIP a)The code doesn't remove any fields. `nullFields` is a Python list object containing the names of fields. The resulting list contains the names of fields with only null values. Don't confuse the remove method of a list object with arcpy.DeleteField_management. b)The only way the code would not check all records is if it found at least one non-null value in every field, which would leave `nullFields` as an empty list.

Comment: Ok, missed it my bad. Still very slack way. Where is : after [:] ? Shouldn't it be isNull(x.name) ?

Comment: @FelixIP +1 for noticing those. Code has been corrected.